# For_each disks Module ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using the module to create my EC2 instances. I am using a for_each to loop through my variable which contains the EC2 info, including ebs volumes.

It looks something like this:

```
ec2_info = {
  server1 = {
    name              = ""
    instance_type     = ""
    key_pair          = ""
    placement_group   = ""
    subnet_id         = ""
    disk_info = {
      disk1 = {
        type              = "gp3"
        iops              = 3000
        throughput        = null
        availability_zone = "ap-southeast-2b"
        size              = 128
        device_name       = "/dev/sdh"
      },
      disk2 = {
        type              = "gp3"
        iops              = 3000
        throughput        = 300
        availability_zone = "ap-southeast-2b"
        size              = 128
        device_name       = "/dev/sdi"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I am using a `flatten` to be able to get the disk info like this:

```
  info_disk_object = flatten([
    for ec2_key, ec2 in var.ec2_sap_apps : [
      for disk_key, disk in ec2.disk_info : {
        ec2_key           = ec2_key
        disk_key          = disk_key
        type              = disk.type
        iops              = disk.iops
        throughput        = disk.throughput
        availability_zone = disk.availability_zone
        size              = disk.size
        device_name       = disk.device_name
      }
    ]
  ])
```

But when I run the following:

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "this" {
  for_each = {
    for disk in local.info_disk_object : "${disk.ec2_key}.${disk.disk_key}" => disk
  }
  type              = each.value.type
  iops              = each.value.iops
  throughput        = each.value.throughput
  availability_zone = each.value.availability_zone
  size              = each.value.size
  encrypted         = true
  kms_key_id        = var.ebs_keys
  tags              = merge(local.tags, { Name = "${each.value.disk_key}" })
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      # Ignore changes to tags
      tags,
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "this" {
  for_each = {
    for disk in local.info_disk_object : "${disk.ec2_key}.${disk.disk_key}" => disk
  }
  device_name = each.value.device_name
  volume_id   = aws_ebs_volume.this[each.value.disk_key].id
  instance_id = module.this[each.value.ec2_key].id
}
```

I'm getting the following error on my intance_id reference:
`Inappropriate value for attribute "instance_id": string required.`
The module I'm using is returning instance IDs in string because I'm using it like such:
`instance_id = module.this.id[count.index]`
in another tf file.. and it works fine. Is the for_each somehow not using string?

also, the line on the volume id is also throwing this error:
`The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.`
My flatten block gets the correct key disk1, disk2, right? so this line of code:
`volume_id   = aws_ebs_volume.sap_apps1[each.value.disk_key].id`
Should be like:
`volume_id   = aws_ebs_volume.sap_apps1["disk1"].id`
`volume_id   = aws_ebs_volume.sap_apps1["disk2"y].id`
for each iteration of for_each.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you create `module.this`? and What are its outputs?

Comment: `module.this.id[count.index]` isn't the same as `module.this[count.index].id`

Comment: The `module.this` is a module for creating EC2. among it's outputs are the instance id, az, arn, placement group, etc.

Comment: Can you show how do you define and create the module in the parent?